# mod_rewrite not working as expected

Tags: mod-rewrite

i have an issue regarding mod_rewrite ... the url rewrite sems to work fine ... only thing is that the url in the address bar remains the same as it was before rewrite

for example: i want to rewrite www.site.com/page.php?page=merchandise to www.site.com/merchandise. now when i write the url i go to the right page (www.site.com/page.php?page=merchandise) but the address in the address bar remains ( www.site.com/page.php?page=merchandise) where it should be (www.site.com/merchandise)  ... it works fine on the local environmnt...but problems occurs in live environment ...
I'm currently using simple RewriteRule.

The rewrite rule is as followed:

```
RewriteRule ^merchandise$ http://www.mysite.com/page.php?page=merchandise [NC]
```

Its pretty simple and should work. But it does not hide the actual address in the address bar. That's my problem.Otherwise it is going to right page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please give more information: which server, which OS, give the RewriteRule, if it's in the general server configuration or in a vhost configuration or in a .htaccess... we need to know more.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand "it does not hide the actual address in the address bar". What does the use **type** for the URL? And why do you think, once the user has typed the URL, this one will change?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the way `mod_rewrite` has been made for, and you are surprised that is works this way. This is funny :)

And it seems you're mixing things.

`mod_rewrite` is here to hide complex URLs and to make them simpler (generally speaking).

You are wrong when you say
"www.site.com/page.php?page=merchandise" to www.site.com/merchandise"

The real thing is probably the opposite:

- you want the Net surfer to type "`http://www.site.com/merchandise`"
- you want your server to change "`http://www.site.com/merchandise`" to "`http://www.site.com/page.php?page=merchandise`"
- what you didn't get is that 99.9999% of the time webmasters **don't want the client to see the real page is "`http://www.site.com/page.php?page=merchandise`"**

...

And that's what does `mod_rewrite`: it looks at incoming URLs, and modify them **internally**. So the webdevelopper (= you) can transform the URLs using `RewriteRule`'s and make whatever you want but it's *always into the server*. The only exception is when you want to explicitely redirect the client to another URLs, then you can use the "`[F]`" directive which means "Forward".

Hope this helps

Comment: Maybe i put it wrong in words but please check out the edit i made. Hope it explains more.